# Installation of clamav with 404 error

Tags: error-handling, screenshot

Trying to install clamav via the terminal in ubunta and getting 404 error to the clamav install location us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ and security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ locations.

Doesn't download and install clamav.  I can try to install clamav via the software center, but I'm trying to set this up for students to learn Ubuntu and command line.  This is the same image that we have used for the past year, with no issues.

[image]

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo apt-get update` first? it looks like the version in trusty-updates is currently `0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`

Comment: @ steeldriver.  That did the trick.  So I just needed to run the update first, and that is similar to the Windows Updates for Ubuntu and it fixed the Ubuntu platorm so I could install clamav?

For next semester, so that they don't have to run the apt-get update first, what do I need to do to change the image?  Re-download and install the new Ubuntu OS or what?  Sorry, I'm not that familiar with Ubuntu, I'm a Windows guy.  Thanks.

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Answer (score 1):

You should run `sudo apt-get update` then it should work without issue. This will refresh your repos

Comment: That did the trick. So I just needed to run the update first, and that is similar to the Windows Updates for Ubuntu and it fixed the Ubuntu platorm so I could install clamav? For next semester, so that they don't have to run the apt-get update first, what do I need to do to change the image? Re-download and install the new Ubuntu OS or what? Sorry, I'm not that familiar with Ubuntu, I'm a Windows guy. Thanks. –